# Laravel Service Container: Contextual binding on parent class, apply to all children

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to implement contextual binding of a *DatabaseConnectionClass* implementation based on the repository that requires it.

This is required so repostiories fetching data from different databases can do so using the relevant connection.

My database connection interface is as so

```
/**
 * Interface DatabaseConnectionInterface
 *
 * @package App\Database\Connection
 */
interface DatabaseConnectionInterface {

    /**
     * Get the database connection
     *
     * @return Connection
     */
    public function getConnection(): Connection;

}
```

My base repository

```
/**
 * Class MiRepository
 *
 * Base repository centralising connection injection
 *
 * @package App\Repositories\Mi
 */
class MiRepository {

    /**
     * The connection to the database
     *
     * @var DatabaseConnectionInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * MiRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param DatabaseConnectionInterface $connection
     */
    public function __construct(DatabaseConnectionInterface $connection){
        $this->connection = $connection->getConnection();
    }

}
```

An extension of the repository

```
/**
 * Class SchemeRepository
 *
 * @package App\Mi\Repositories
 */
class SchemeRepository extends MiRepository {

    /**
     * Find and return all stored SchemeValidator
     *
     * @return Scheme[]|NULL
     */
    public function findAll(): ?array {
        $results = $this->connection->select('EXEC [webapi_get_products_schemes]');

        if(empty($results)){
            return NULL;
        }

        $schemes = array();
        foreach($results as $result){
            $schemes[] = Scheme::create($result->SCHEMENAME);
        }

        return $schemes;
    }

}
```

The service container binding

```
/**
 * Class MiServiceProvider
 *
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class MiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->when(MiRepository::class)
            ->needs(DatabaseConnectionInterface::class)
            ->give(function(){
                return new MiDatabaseConnection();
            });
    }
}
```

The problem is when i try to inject an extension of the base repository i do not think the contextual binding is triggered and i get the exception

```
Target [App\\Common\\Database\\Connection\\DatabaseConnectionInterface] is not instantiable ...
```

Has anyone had this problem before, and know of way to use contextual binding on a parent class and have it triggered for all children?

I know this can be achieved by implementing contextual binding definitions for all child classes this seems a bit clunky however.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, because PHP and dependency injection as a whole relies on reflection to know the classes the constructors are looking for, it's basically doing a string pattern match to find the right binding. Because you haven't defined a bound string for your extended classes, it can't find a related bind function. So I suspect what you want to do won't work.

The work around to avoid too much repetitive code might be:

```
public function register()
{
    foreach($repo in ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']) {

        $this->app->when($repo . Repository::class)
            ->needs(DatabaseConnectionInterface::class)
            ->give(function () use ($repo) {
                $theClass = $repo . 'DatabaseConnection';
                return new $theClass();
            });
    }
}
```